# How to print only the Scope and Policy items in Get-ExecutionPolicy?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

This should be trivial for a Windows guru, but seem to be rather daunting for a *nix historian.

I want to print *only* the `Scope` and `ExecutionPolicy` Values in the table, obtained by:

```bsh
# Actual output:
(Get-ExecutionPolicy -List)

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine          Bypass


# Expected output:
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine          Bypass
```

This is super trivial in Bash, by just piping to `tail +4`. According to other posts, the PS equivalent should be `| Select-Object -Last 5`, but that doeasn't work.

**How to do this in pure PowerShell?**

I can get each separately with:

```
(Get-ExecutionPolicy -List).Scope
(Get-ExecutionPolicy -List).ExecutionPolicy
```

But this look ugly when putting them together again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List | Format-Table -hideTableHeader
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving me crazy for hours. Trying things like *skip, select, first, last*, etc.

Comment: I had to wait 8 minutes!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on mhhollomon's answer, PowerShell has default output for objects based on .xml files stashed in its folder. For the `Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy` objects output by `Get-ExecutionPolicy` it uses `Format-Table` by default when no other formatting is explicitly specified. Since that happens at the end of the pipeline, any `Select-Object` commands that you attempted will happen before the end of the pipeline, so you are only removing `Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy` objects from reaching the end of the pipeline. The remaining objects make it to the end of the pipeline, and the scripting engine then checks how they should be output, and generates a table with the remaining objects.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: To elaborate on the fact that both **text** columns are **right** justified: they both represent enumerations you'll see when you `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List |ConvertTo-Json` or cast to an [int] (+1)